# java priority queue insert(int p, E e)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have to implement a priority queue using an array.

How do I attach the priority to the element I want to insert in the array. I want the array to be sorted, so that when you insert the array it is kept sorted where the beginning of the array is the element with highest priority and the end is the element with lowest priority.

I've tried to make a private class Entry which has a key and value attribute, but my insert is still not working. Any ideas on how to get started?

```
private class Entry{
    private int key;
    private E value;

    public Entry(int key, E value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}

public class PrioritetArraySorteret<E> implements PrioritetADT<E> {
    private int capacity = 5;
    private Entry S[];
    private int size;

    public PrioritetArraySorteret() {
       S = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
       size = 0;
    }

   @Override
   public void insert(int p, E e) {
      Entry temp = new Entry(p, e);

       int i = 0;
      while(i < S.length) {
        Entry t = S[i];
        if (t.compareTo(temp) == -1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            int j = i;
            S[j + 1] = S[j];
            j++;
        }

       }
       S[i] = temp;
       size++;
}
```

***An extra question***

How do I make an array of Entry with the length of capacity? It gives an error if I type Entry instead of E in the constructor.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be  cast to [Lopgave5Prioritet.PrioritetArraySorteret$Entry;)

Comment: I suggest you write something which compiles first and build on that.

Comment: @Kowser - so what? Nice question, although there are basically 2 questions. A good suggestion if you want a response would be to split it up in Stackoverflow questions for the best result :)

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen if it's homework then the aim on SO is to help the asker understand _how_ to do the implementation, etc, rather than pointing them in the direction of an API or whatever to stop their boss breathing down their back :)

Answer (score -2):

There are different issues but one that looks incorrect is this:

Change

```
S = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
```

to

```
S = new Entry[capacity];
```

Comment: It cannot accept new Entry[capacity]. it says something about it is not matching the generic type.

Comment: She is right. This is because of type erasure. The given answer will not work.